# What is the "selector" in the on() jQuery function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have the following working code, 'hi' is printed to the Console when I click on the `a` tag with id `info-toggle`.

`<a href="#" id="info-toggle">More info</a>`

```
$.ajax({
  'url': '/maps/building/' + marker.urlID,
  'dataType': 'json',
  'success': function(data) {
    infowindow.setContent(data.html_short);
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
    $(document).on('click', '#info-toggle', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      console.log('hi');
    });
  }
});
```

However, if I modify the `.on()` call to the following

```
$('#info-toggle').on('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log('hi');
});
```

'hi' is not printed.

From the docs:

> When a selector is provided, the event handler is referred to as
>   delegated. The handler is not called when the event occurs directly on
>   the bound element, but only for descendants (inner elements) that
>   match the selector. jQuery bubbles the event from the event target up
>   to the element where the handler is attached (i.e., innermost to
>   outermost element) and runs the handler for any elements along that
>   path matching the selector.

Is the `selector` there referring to the selector within the parentheses `$()` or the second argument in the `.on()` function, `.on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler(eventObject) )`?

Comment: The second one. The first one must exist in the DOM at the time `.on` is called.

Comment: The first method is attaching the click handler to the `document`. The second one is trying to attach it to an element with an id of `info-toggle`, if the element doesn't exist when this code it called no handler will be attached. Does the element exist when this code is called?

Comment: I would think that `.on()` is being called after the html is displayed in the `infowindow`, but I'm not sure.